How to handle Accessibility Insights for Windows warning on each list item in syslistview32 in report mode?
I am testing my application with Accessibility Insights for Windows. The application has a list control (aka "SyslistView32") running in report mode only. Now, for each list item in this list control, I get a warning with the following wording when running FastPass against it:

The given element is expected to have the following structure: ListItem and NoChild(IsContentElement)

In the window labeled "Fix the following", the following recommendation can be read:

Set the element to conform to the following structure: ListItem and NoChild(IsContentElement).

I honestly do not have the faintest idea what to do here, and what both the warning text and the recommended fix mean in this case.
I would be happy if someone could explain with better words what the problem is, and if possible, what a potential fix could look like.
I have tried to reproduce this with a simple application using a list control in report mode that has each list item column filled with arbitrary text, and AI for Windows shows the exact same error here as well. I have not tried if this warning is shown in other list control modes as well.
I would have expected a much less cryptic description of the warning, and a better recommendation for a fix. AI for Windows typically has wonderful recommendations for potential fixes along with code samples, but this one completely leaves me in the dark.

Click the New Issue button to state your concerns and recommendations.

Refer to the thread: https://github.com/microsoft/accessibility-insights-windows/pull/281 It seems an issue, I suggest you could post the issue to the GitHub for better help.

@SimonMourier: FastPass, as far as I understand it, is a mode that tests your whole application as it is currently displayed. You choose the second item "Entire app" in the "What to select" combo box, hover over your app and press Shift-F8. Then a FastPass run happens against the current state of your application.
